# Uniqueness of solutions of Cauchy problem with nonzero function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the initial value problem
$$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)), \\ y(x_0)=y_0,$$
where the function $f \colon D \to \mathbb R$ is defined and continuous on some open set $D \subseteq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ and $(x_0, y_0) \in D$. Is the following statement true?

> This problem cannot have two distinct solutions on some interval $[x_0, x_1]$ if $$\forall (x,y) \in D \colon f(x, y) \ne 0.$$

If $f$ does not depend on $x$, the answer seems to be positive, i.e. we have some kind of uniqueness theorem here, but my intuition tells me that it is, generally, wrong. Can you provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuitions are both correct. The answer to your first question is positive, see, e.g., my answer to [Existence and uniqueness of solution of IVP with separation of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798995/existence-and-uniqueness-of-solution-of-ivp-with-separation-of-variables/2799153#2799153).  Regarding the second, consider 
$$
y'(x) = 1 + 2 \sqrt{\max\{y(x)-x, 0\}}
$$
with initial condition $y(0) = 0$.  The function $1 + 2 \sqrt{\max\{y-x, 0\}}$ is continuous and positive on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.  Both the functions
$$
\varphi(x) = x, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$
\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{ for } x \le 0 
\\
x + x^2 & \text{ for } x > 0 
\end{cases}
$$
satisfy the IVP.