Improper integral as Primitive
Let $f\in C(a,b],$ $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty$ and $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ exists (finite) as Improper integral.
Can the expression $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ be considered as a Primitive of the function $f(x)$ on a half-interval $(a,b]$?
As I see, the function $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is defined on the segment $[a,b]$.
Due to additivity, it can be investigated as ordinary Riemann integral in each point $x\in(a,b]$ using $F(x+\delta )-F(x)=\int_x^{x+\delta}f(t)dt,$ where $[x,x+\delta]\subset(a,b]$ (for $b:$ $[b-\delta,b]\subset(a,b]$).
Therefore the function $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $(a,b]$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ here.
Have I made a mistake somewhere?
If not, can I relax the restrictions on the $f(x)$?

That is correct. What are your doubts about it?

I think you are generally right. Only one problem: is $\displaystyle\int_a^af(t){\rm d}t=0$ really well-defined when $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=a$?

@MartinR This happens when you look for a trick everywhere :)
By the way, does this mean that when I have a general integral $\int\limits_{x_0}^{x} \frac{\varphi'(\xi)}{g(\varphi(\xi))} d\xi = \int\limits_{x_0}^{x} h(\xi) , d\xi, $ of a solution to a differential equation $\frac{\varphi'(x)}{g(\varphi(x))} = h(x)$ (as in the link below), this integral can be in an improper sense and the condition of the Cauchy problem can be given at a singular point of h $x_0$?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798995/existence-and-uniqueness-of-solution-of-ivp-with-separation-of-variables?rq=1

@JCQ
we can simply define the antiderivative by zero at $a$ as a limit of the remainder of the improper integral

There is a class of indefinite integrals that can be reduced to elliptic integrals with three or four singular points. In Gradshteyn/Rhyzik (3.13–3.17 Expressions that can be reduced to square roots of third- and fourth-
degree polynomials and their products with rational functions)   they are tabulated as definite integrals with one upper or lower  boundary fixed at one of the singular points $(-\infty, a_1,\dots \infty)$ that yield completely different algebraic functions with different circles of convergency.
